# Mobile Wallet - Which problem is trying solve?

Tags: mobile, users, payment, app

Currently I am working for project which is related with the Mobile Wallet.

Could you please anyone help me to understand that **which Problem the mobile wallet or phone payment are trying to solve?.** How its helpful a user?.

It would be great if you can tell me the pros and cons of the mobile payment or wallets.

Comment: I've never used one but isn't it just so people don't have to carry a real physical wallet/cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the convenience. Having everything in on place can **arguably** be considered more secure (Example: 1Password), but mainly, it's so you're not limited by the physical constraints of carrying everything.

An extension of the Mobile Wallet are the apps that collect and store all your card numbers (like Air Miles, Grocery Points, Movie Points, etc). I would normally never carry all these cards on me because these 8+ cards wouldn't fit in my wallet.

Digitizing makes life more convenient.